# Handle multiple content-types/accept headers in request chain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, http-headers

I have the following problem:
I have a service A that can request a number of other services (B-E). The services B-E version their resources based on the Accept header which can look like "vnd.example+json;version=1".
Now the user wants to request the latest version of the resource and makes a request with the Accept header: "vnd.example+json;version=1" to Service A (because Service A is the proxy between the user and the rest of the services). However, service A has the following in its endpoint:
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} therefore Service A throws the following error message: "status":406, "error": "Not Acceptable", "message": "Could not find acceptable representation".
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the `produces`. It doesn't do what you think it does (it is only used for mapping **not** for enforcing the returned content type).

Comment: Found out that I can simply say MediaType.ALL_VALUES. 
Which one is better removing the produces or the all_values?

Comment: Nothing is more or less the same as all, so it doesn't really matter.